# Hi I cannot create a user because I have errors on my code on word `` document '' in the code

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble coding on flutter following the update made on firebase_auth version 0.18, a lot of the methods are loaded like AuthResult to UserCredentil, FirebaseUse to User,
So how do I create a user because here is my code that refuses with the old syntax, I am between to use the latest version of firebase_auth 0.20

Answer (score 0):

```
  User user  = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: UserCredential resutl = await  _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: motdepasse);
                        await collectionUtil.document(_idUtil()).setData({
                          'idUtil': _idUtil(),
                          'nomcomplet' : nomComplet,
                          'emailUtil' : email

                        });

Comment: here is my code to create a user but i still have errors

Comment: the first problem is that the android store editor does not recognize the document syntax in the code

Comment: if you look at my code on UserCredential resutl = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email: email, password: password); await collectionUtil.document (_idUtil ()). setData ({'idUtil': _idUtil (), 'fullname': fullName, 'emailUtil': email}); the collectionUtil.document syntax not recognized by android studio

Comment: await _auth
                              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: Email, password: Password)
                              .then((result) {});
donot use UserCredential

Comment: if this code doesn't work change the firebase rules

Comment: thanks with your reaction, it just worked